# How to isolate files in S3 bucket by directory?

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 bucket `mybucket` containing three files in the following directory structure

```
a/b/c/d/some_file.txt
a/b/d/d/some_file2.txt
x/y/z/yet_another_file.txt
```

I can list all of the files using the following:

```
import boto3

# Extract the files from the s3 bucket
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
bucket_files = [x.key for x in bucket.objects.all()]
```

Although this will yield all of the files in the s3 bucket, e.g.:

```
a/b/c/d/some_file.txt
a/b/d/d/some_file2.txt
x/y/z/yet_another_file.txt
```

How can I list just the files in `a`? e.g.

```
a/b/c/d/some_file.txt
a/b/d/d/some_file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` with `Prefix`:

```
import boto3

# Extract the files from the s3 bucket
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
bucket_files = [x.key for x in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='a/')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket', Prefix='a')
```